# xCode Organizer Upload Taking Forever?

Tags: ios, xcode

Just uploading my first app through xCode's Organiser. I had quite a bit of trouble with validation, but eventually got it, and it validated okay. Now after pressing upload, it is just taking forever to upload, it is just staying on the following screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGIvw.png

The Organiser estimated the application (when on the app store) would be 1.5 mb, but the folder containing everything for the app is about 21 mb. It has been 25 minutes now (since 6:05pm), is this time unusual for a 21 mb upload?

**EDIT:** Also, I looked at the Activity Monitor to check the upload speed, and the bandwidth seems to be very low (see link below), is something wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIHd1.png

Thank you.

Comment: It does a few other checks before it actually performs the upload, so give it some more time.  Also maybe the server is not responding.

Comment: It has been 2 hours now and still the same screen. Should I stop it and try through 'Application Loader' or try through Organiser again?
@borrrden

Comment: It's probably not a bad idea.  If it happens again there is likely a network issue.

Comment: Alright, I am trying the Application Loader now.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't know how to upload via Application Loader, as it needs an IPA file? I am just going to try organiser again.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of firewall protection enabled .Try to disable it and it will go through authentication process and your binary will be uploaded.